# Capturing a Rectangle

Tags: vb.net

This works. It draws a simple Rectangle on a panel:

```
    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim fPen As Pen
    g = aPanel.CreateGraphics()

    fPen = New Pen(Color.Blue)
    Dim PointX As Point = New Point(10, 20)
    Dim PointY As Point = New Point(50, 50)

    g.DrawRectangle(fPen, PointY.X, PointY.Y, 50, 50)
```

Everything is an object - but how do i reference this ractangle?
I'd like to use this rectangle as one of the arguments when creating an ellipse later on in the code (i.e. draw the ellipse in the rectangle) - why can't I do the following?

```
    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim fPen As Pen
    g = aPanel.CreateGraphics()

    fPen = New Pen(Color.Blue)
    Dim PointX As Point = New Point(10, 20)
    Dim PointY As Point = New Point(50, 50)

    Dim r As Rectangle
    r = New Rectangle(g.DrawRectangle(fPen, PointY.X, PointY.Y, 50, 50)) '<<<errors here
    g.DrawEllipse(fPen, r)
```

Comment: `DrawRectangle` doesn't return anything (it is a `Sub`).

Comment: Anything you draw using CreateGraphics will disappear if the window is minimized or if another window passes in front of it.  You should do your painting in the Paint event of the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your rectangle and use its values:

```
Dim r As New Rectangle(10, 50, 50, 50)

g.DrawRectangle(fPen, r.Location.X, r.Location.Y, r.Width, r.Height)
g.DrawEllipse(fPen, r)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`DrawRectangle` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6hb4eba.aspx) on the `Graphics` object, doesn't return any value as it is a `Sub`.

You first have to create an instance of the [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx), which you can later use to draw the rectangle and the Ellipse.

```
Dim pointY As New Point(50, 50)
Dim rectSize As New Size(50, 50)
Dim rect As New Rectangle(pointY, rectSize)

g.DrawRectangle(fPen, rect)
g.DrawEllipse(fPen, rect)
```

Comment: There is no need to use different pens, it wont cause any trouble painting all the things you want.